# Many to many relation on same table

Tags: symfony1, many-to-many, symfony-1.4, propel

I've got a little problem with many to many relations on the same table using Symfony 1.4 with the Propel ORM. My schema.yml looks like this:

```yml
propel:
  item:
    _attributes: { phpName: Item }
    id: { phpName: Id, type: INTEGER, size: '10', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    type_id: { phpName: TypeId, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true, foreignTable: type, foreignReference: id, onDelete: RESTRICT, onUpdate: RESTRICT }
    owner_id: { phpName: OwnerId, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true, foreignTable: owner, foreignReference: id, onDelete: RESTRICT, onUpdate: RESTRICT }
    place_id: { phpName: PlaceId, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true, foreignTable: place, foreignReference: id, onDelete: RESTRICT, onUpdate: RESTRICT }
    picture_id: { phpName: PictureId, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: false, foreignTable: picture, foreignReference: id, onDelete: RESTRICT, onUpdate: RESTRICT }
    supplier_id: { phpName: SupplierId, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: false, foreignTable: supplier, foreignReference: id, onDelete: RESTRICT, onUpdate: RESTRICT }
    name: { phpName: Name, type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: true }
    amount: { phpName: Amount, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true }
    wished_amount: { phpName: WishedAmount, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true }
    costs: { phpName: Costs, type: DECIMAL, size: '7', scale: '2', required: true }
    description: { phpName: Description, type: LONGVARCHAR, required: false }
    use_until: { phpName: UseUntil, type: DATE, required: false }
    last_used: { phpName: LastUsed, type: TIMESTAMP, required: false }
    last_updated: { phpName: LastUpdated, type: TIMESTAMP, required: false }
    _indexes: { item_FI_1: [type_id], item_FI_2: [owner_id], item_FI_3: [place_id], item_FI_4: [picture_id], item_FI_5: [supplier_id] }

 item_has_item:
    item_id: { type: INTEGER, required: true, foreignTable: item, foreignAlias: item, foreignReference: id, primaryKey: true}
    parent_item_id: { type: INTEGER, required: true, foreignTable: item, foreignAlias: parent_item, foreignReference: id, primaryKey: true}
    _indexes: { item_has_item_FKIndex1: [item_id], item_has_item_FKIndex2: [parent_item_id] }
```

However, the needed `admin_double_list` in the admin generator does not appear automatically. It does, when the second `foreignTable` is adjusted to another table, for example `sf_guard_user`. I've read that this could be fixed in Propel 1.3, but I don't know which Propel version is included with Symfony 1.4.

I hope I gave enough information for my problem to be solved by you guys. Otherwise I will have to make another table which holds the items that have child item, like this:

> Item <---- Item_has_item <---- Combined_item

**EDIT AFTER REACTION FROM j0k**

After the reaction from j0k, I did update the sfPropelORMPlugin, and it did recognise the relation. However, I still got an error while saving (only when a relation is made):

```
Unable to execute INSERT statement [INSERT INTO `item_has_item` (`ITEM_ID`) VALUES (:p0)]
[wrapped: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a 
child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SI/item_has_item`, CONSTRAINT 
`item_has_item_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`))]
```

I have found, after a long extensive search, that the form generator fails to correctly understand the many-to-many relation on the same table. In the function saveItemHasItemList($con = null):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ItemHasItemPeer::ITEM_ID, $this->object->getPrimaryKey());
ItemHasItemPeer::doDelete($c, $con);

$values = $this->getValue('item_has_item_list');
if (is_array($values))
    {
      foreach ($values as $value)
      {
        $obj = new ItemHasItem();
        $obj->setItemId($this->object->getPrimaryKey());
        $obj->setItemId($value);
        $obj->save();
      }
    }
```

As you can see, the ItemId is twice set, while the ParentItemId is not set, hence the constraint value. It should be generated as:

```
$c->add(ItemHasItemPeer::ITEM_ID, $this->object->getPrimaryKey());
$c->add(ItemHasItemPeer::PARENT_ITEM_ID, $this->object->getPrimaryKey());
```

&&

```
$obj->setParentItemId($this->object->getPrimaryKey());
$obj->setItemId($value);
```

This solves the saving problem, however, it still does not show the already selected relations. To solve that, you should also change the updateDefaultsFromObject():

```
foreach ($this->object->getItemHasItemsRelatedByItemId() as $obj)
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($this->object->getItemHasItemsRelatedByParentItemId() as $obj)
```

Remember, these functions are located in form/base/BaseItemForm.class.php, but the functions should be overwritten in /form/ItemForm.class.php.

I believe this is an Propel bug, so I will post it tomorrow on the Propel TRAC.

Comment: Better report bug on [Github](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel).

Comment: Corresponding GitHub ticket: [Ticket](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/issues/143)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the last symfony 1.4, it uses [Propel 1.4.2](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor).

You should try to use a [new version](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin) of the Propel Plugin. It uses Propel 1.6.

Comment: Thank you, but however, another error appears, as described above in my edit.